# refreshControl gives "undefined is not a function..." in react-native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch, uirefreshcontrol

I'm trying to add refresh functionality in my ScrollView, but when trying to refresh I get this error:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0,_reactNative.fetchData)()')
```

I have followed the example [in the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol.html)

Here is my code

```
class Schedule extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      refreshing: false
    };
  }

  _onRefresh() {
    this.setState({refreshing: true});
    fetchData().then(() => {
      this.setState({refreshing: false});
    });
  }
 render() {
  return (
<View>
 <ScrollView
      style={{backgroundColor: "white"}} scrollEnabled={true} horizontal={false}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
        />
      }
    >
   <View>
    //...Content I'm trying to refresh
   </View>

</View>
</ScrollView>
  )
 }
}
```

I can't imagine there being anything wrong with the code itself, as it's taken straight from the example. There shouldn't be any problems with the imports either

```
import {View, ScrollView, RefreshControl, fetchData } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: I don't think fetchData is an export from 'react-native' you need to define your own 'fetchData' function in your component.

Comment: You have mismatching tags: `<View> <ScrollView> </View> </ScrollView>`

Comment: I'm sure I do :) Removed a bunch of stuff before posting so things got mixed up!

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the `fetchData` function it's not in the `react-native` module.

Comment: Any idea on how to create a fetchData function which gets your local views?

Comment: The name fetchDate suggests that it gets data from an api, when you receive this data you will update your state with it.